# Android Studio fail add libs Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, android-studio, universal-image-loader

Android-Universal-Image-Loader(https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) is my favorite library.

But it can't add libs when i use Android Studio(use 0.1.5 version).

i know how to add libs in Android Studio
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/16628496/397457)

when i add Android-Universal-Image-Loader libs to Android Studio. Editor error about "can't reslove R". i try this Max OSX(i try too Windows but fail. Windows error message => "Gradle: error: package com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core does not exist". but Editor no error message. only show when i run application)

other libs like Gson no problem. but only Android-Universal-Image-Loader have this problem.

Your Android Studio success add Android-Universal-Image-Loader? if success tell me how to.

Comment: are you adding jar file?

Comment: I will suggest then add those source code. java files and packages.

Answer (score 23):

I just added the universal-image-loader like this:

Firstly download the universal-image-loader-1.8.5-with-sources.jar.

(For 5/2014. universal-image-loader-1.9.2.jar works great. Don't need the "with-sources" file.)

Then put it on my MyAppProject/MyApp/libs.

Right clicking on universal-image-loader-1.8.5-with-sources.jar i add it as a library with the default configuration.

Finally on MyAppProject/MyApp/build.gradle add the following:

```
dependencies {
compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.8.5-with-sources.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 8):

From the error "*package com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core does not exist*", it seems like you have not added the source as the library. Right click the "universal-image-loader-1.8.4.jar" file under the libs folder and from the context menu, click `"Add as a library"` option.

If after this you are getting the "**ClassDefNotFoundException**", please follow the following steps:

1. Add the library to the project.
2. Edit your Gradle build file and add the dependency for the UIL in it
   [image: Add dependency in build.gradle]
3. Close Android Studio
4. Open command prompt and go to the project's root folder (you will find 'gradlew' file there) and clean your build by issuing the clean command `C:\CarApplicationProject> gradlew clean`
5. Restart Android Studio.

Comment: No need to do gradlew clean, you can just go to build->rebuild project and it will clean etc for you without the need to restart android studio at all

Answer (score 3):

1.Put the jar (in my case, gson-2.2.4.jar) into the libs folder.

2.Ensure that compile files ('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar') is in your build.gradle file.

3.Now Click on the "Sync Project with Gradle files"(Left to AVD manager Button on the topbar).

After I did the above three, it started working fine.

Answer (score 2):

> There are two ways to use Universal Image Loader

1. By `downloading Ja`r and add it to `lib` folder and

   **compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.5-with-sources.jar')**
2. Simply add `gradle dependency`

   **compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'**

And here is a [quick tutorial link](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Quick-Setup)