# does ParseImageView cache ParseFile

Tags: android, caching, parse-platform

Does ParseImageView cache ParseFile's in Android. If it caches parseFile, How can i find the path of those files in my android device.

```
ParseImageView imageView = (ParseImageView) findViewById(android.R.id.icon);
 // The placeholder will be used before and during the fetch, to be replaced by the fetched image
 // data.
 imageView.setPlaceholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.placeholder));
 imageView.setParseFile(file);
 imageView.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
   @Override
   public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
     Log.i("ParseImageView",
         "Fetched! Data length: " + data.length + ", or exception: " + e.getMessage());
   }
 });
```

Comment: Picasso is the only way to go here.

Answer (score 15):

Looks like [@suresh kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2794579/suresh-kumar) is dead right, so this question is settled with **"no"**, but having run into this trouble I wanted to drop some code in here to get around it.

I use [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) for URL image loading, and it supports a lot of configuration options for caching and display. Set it up in your Application class with (at time of writing):

```
    //Create image options.
    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.button_default)
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisc(true)
        .build();

    //Create a config with those options.
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
        .build();

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

And then use it with Parse where you'd like to load and cache your image:

```
        ParseImageView itemImage = (ParseImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_item);
        ParseFile photoFile = item.getParseFile("picture");
        if (photoFile != null) {
            //Get singleton instance of ImageLoader
            ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
            //Load the image from the url into the ImageView.
            imageLoader.displayImage(photoFile.getUrl(), itemImage);
        }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: An incredible tip, thanks ..  Just FTR the iOS equivalent is DLImageLoader (eg, http://stackoverflow.com/a/19115912/294884 ) ... that may help any "Mac to Android" devs googling in the future.  Thanks again so much.  Bounty en route!

Comment: Glad to help! (Interesting how much competition there is amongst iOS images loaders too. I've used SDWebImage out of habit.)

Comment: **footnote** cacheOnDisc would seem to be now cacheOnDisk ("k").

Comment: **footnote** this incredibly helpful answer will with android studio: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17521288/294884

Comment: However!  I've since experimented with Picasso.  I do think it's even better.  With a long ListView (about 100 full-screen images) I was getting a lot of stutter with UIL which I could not resolve.  I changed to Picasso -- and it's done.  So, Picasso worked for me!

Comment: ParseFile is limited in this respect. your solution is brilliant, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

ParseImageView doesn't cache ParseFile, It is only used to display the image file stored in Parse.com. [See this](https://parse.com/questions/image-caching-for-android)

and [this](https://www.parse.com/questions/caching-a-parsefile-image-offline-in-android)