# Get Parsefile to ImageView

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I want to get file from parse to ImageView. I'm try to get by "getDataInBackgound" But when I call to this method' UI is stuck and I get the last image.

```
ParseFile image = tableParseObjects.getParseFile(PARSE_IMAGES);

                    image.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                            Bitmap bitpic = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            bitpic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                            vectorSample.setPic(bitpic);

                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to load the image using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or the ImageLoader class. I had the same doubt and I used a ParseImageView too. This is my code:

Retrieve from parse.com the ParseFile (the image) with an asynctask:

```
public class BackgroundQuery extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Object> {
    private String id;

    public BackgroundQuery(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        Object o = null;
        try {
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(params[0]
                    .getClass().getSimpleName());
            query.whereEqualTo("objectId", id);
            List<ParseObject> result = query.find();

            if (result != null) {
                for (ParseObject obj : result) {
                    o = obj.getParseFile("photo"); // Photo is the ParseFile
                }
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return o;
    }
}
```

In your layout use this like an ImageView:

```
<com.parse.ParseImageView
        android:id="@id/imgv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true />
```

Use this line for load the picture in the ParseImageView:

> Picasso.with(this).load(parsefile.getUrl()).into(parseimageview);

An alternative to load bigger pics quickly it´s using an ImageLoader. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169259/does-parseimageview-cache-parsefile).

Hope this help :)